# TypeError: Undefined is not an object(evaluating: 'posts.map')

Tags: react-native, api, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am facing an issue when I fetch the data from API it gives me an undefined is not an object error in the map function at index.js file. I am using JSON placeholder API for fetching the data

**This is my action.js file**

```
import * as types from './actionType';

const fetchPostStart=()=>({
    type:types.FETCH_POST_START
});
const fetchPostSuccess=(posts)=>({
    type:types.FETCH_POST_SUCCESS,
    payload: posts,
});
const fetchPostFail=(error)=>({
    type:types.FETCH_POST_FAIL,
    payload:error,
});

  export const fetchPosts=()=>{
    return function (dispatch){
        dispatch(fetchPostStart());
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((response)=>{
            const posts = response.data;
            dispatch(fetchPostSuccess(posts));
        }).catch((error)=>{
            dispatch(fetchPostFail(error.message));
            
        })

    }
```

**This is my index.js file**

```
import { View, Text,Button ,StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import App from './App'
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import  {fetchPosts}  from './src/redux/action'
const Index = () => {
  const { posts, loading } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state.data }));
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 

  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>redux</Text>
    <Button onPress={() => dispatch(fetchPosts())} title="Fetch Data" />
    {!loading ? (posts.map ((post) => <Text key={post.id}>{post.title}</Text>)): (<Text>loading...</Text>)   }
    </View>
    
  )
}
const styles= StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
 
})
export default Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) to decode the response body.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => ...)
```

Comment: If I tried the solution that you suggested I get the unhandled promise rejection Error: Actions may not have an undefined 'type' property.